# UIWebView log message iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7

I am developing an app that use web browser after I built it I got this message:

```
UITextField -webView called. This method is no longer supported with the new text architecture
```

So what do I need to use right now?

Comment: This has happened to me when I accidentally perform some keyboard shortcut in the textField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, `UITextfield` used a `UIWebView` internally for rendering rich text. This has been done away with the release of TextKit (or as they say it, "the new text architecture"). If you need to render web content, this should certainly be done by creating and using a `UIWebView` directly.

Comment: The issue is people are getting this message and they are not trying to display any web content. We are just putting UITextFields in XIB and this error gets shown for no reason.

Comment: @Fraggle are you trying to use attributed text in the text field?

Comment: No UITextField type=Plain in XIB. A username and password box. Where username is an email, and password has secureTextEntry=YES, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug on the iOS 7 simulator.