# Weird Error of UITextField and UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitextfield

I just got another weird thing after upgrading to `Xcode 5.1`… As I am typing in my `UITextField`, a message is displayed in the console saying

```
UITextField -webView called. This method is no longer supported with the new text architecture
```

What kind of a message is this..? `UITextField`..`UIWebView`… oh come on… this `Xcode 5.1` upgrade is giving me all sorts of issues…

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this seems to be an error from an internal framework of Apple and be more interpreted as warning. Probably fixed soon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073960/uitextfield-webview-no-longer-supported

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778951/uiwebview-log-message-ios-7

Comment: @KumarKl nice effort i am also facing problem related to `UITextField` [Please review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631235/uitextfield-strange-behaviour-when-entering-text)

Comment: Before iOS7 all the label text field and text views objects used web views in the background to format attributed strings. Since TextKit the method calls that ran that are deprecated. As noted above it's not an error for you to worry over but it would be a nice thing to go log it on bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "Patrick Goley"

Previously, `UITextfield` used a `UIWebView` internally for rendering rich text. This has been done away with the release of `TextKit` (or as they say it, "the new text architecture"). If you need to render web content, this should certainly be done by creating and using a `UIWebView` directly.